# Why does copying an XML file from Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit to Windows XP 32-bit change the file?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, xml

**What I do:**

1. Copy an xml file (ctrl+C) on a Win Server 2008 machine.
2. Minimize mstsc.exe (remote connection app).
3. Paste the xml file on to my WinXP machine (ctrl+V).

**The result:**

All of the original contents are still present but another bit is appended at the end of it.

E.g. the proper end of the file looks something like this:

```
<ApplicationName>MyApp</ApplicationName>
</ReceivePort>
</ReceivePortCollection>
<PartyCollection xsi:nil="true" />
</BindingInfo>
```

But, after the copy, it looks like this:

```
<ApplicationName>MyApp</ApplicationName>
    </ReceivePort>
    </ReceivePortCollection>
    <PartyCollection xsi:nil="true" />
    </BindingInfo>al, PublicKeyToken=3zzf3xxxadyyy35" Type="1" TrackingOption="ServiceStartEnd MessageSendReceive PipelineEvents" Description="" />
      <ReceivePipelineData xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendPipeline xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendPipelineData xsi:nil="true" />
      <Enable>true</Enable>
      <ReceiveHandler Name="WCF_OracleDB_Rx" HostTrusted="false">
        <TransportType Name="WCF OracleDB" Capabilities="779" Configuratio
```

The extra bits it adds are things that come from earlier in the XML file. If I do the copy multiple times, the extra bits are always exactly the same but another XML file will add different lines.

**Extra information:**

If I copy/paste the file, as above, but first enclose it into a zip file I do not have the same problem. I.e. the file copies properly and without any extra surprises.

If I do a copy/paste from a Windows Explorer window that's opened to the folder on the remote machine, I do not have the same behavior. I.e. the file copies properly and without any extra surprises.

**Question:**

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find a page in the MS KB to acknowledge it, but I think this is a bug in the terminal services client - in which some kinds of text file, when pasted this way, will have data from somewhere in the middle of the file added to the end of it.

You can workaround this by either using client drive mappings (eg \tsclient\c) or by zipping up the file before you copy/paste it.

Have you updated your Remote Desktop client (mstsc.exe) to version 7?  That might play more nicely with the Server 2008 clipboard.

RDC version 7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084/